# XmlSerialize an object that can be null, DbNull, int, bool. string or double

Tags: c#, .net, xmlserializer

I have a class that has an `object` field that should be able to hold either `null`, `DbNull`, `int`s, `string`s, `bool`s or `double`s. So far I've been able to have the `XmlSerializer` automatically detect the data type and serialize my class properly except when my `object` is a `DbNull`.

I get this error: `"The type System.DBNull was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically."`.

What would it be the easiest workaround here?

There is really not much code to show. This could be my code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public object MyMultiTypesObject { get; set; }
}
```

`MyMultiTypesObject` will receive a value that will be of any of the types I mentioned above because it will be the conversion from a primitive javascript data type to a C# data type when handled by a `WebBrowser`. AFAIK, these are all the types you will get. For instance, `number`s turn into `double`s or `int`s, `undefined` turns into `null`, and `null` turns into `DbNull`.

I'm serializing it the way you would normally serialize a class with an `XmlSerializer`, kinda like this:

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
ser.Serialize(File.Create(@"C:\file.xml"), mc);
```

Comment: any chance of seeing some code, so we can see your current approach?

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error message tells you to do? Did that help?

Comment: @GregBeech: `XmlInclude` will only work on a class declaration. I'm using `object`, not a custom class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite System.DBNull class can be serialized, System.DBNull is designed to have only one instance per AppDomain. These types are frequently called singletons. If you have a field refers to a DBNull object, serializing and deserializing it should not cause new DBNull object to exist in the AppDomain. That's why default serialization mechanism refuses to serialize it.

I think you have two ways:

1. Do not use of DBNull value in cases when you have to serialize fields
2. Implement **IXmlSerializable** in your class and make your own serialization mechanism

Hope this great article will help you: [How to Implement IXmlSerializable Correctly](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/ImplementIXmlSerializable.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to xml serialize DBNull. see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923(v=vs.110).aspx

Tag your class like:

```
[Serializable]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("PropertyEntry", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.SerializationFormatter)]
public class PropertyEntry {}
```